# Is the derivative of a continuously differentiable function always integrable?

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, continuity

I know that $f(x)$ is bounded by the extreme value theorem, because $f(x)$ is defined on a closed bounded interval. Now, how can I prove that its derivative is integrable knowing that it is continuous? Or, is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any continuous function on a closed and bounded interval $[a,b]$ is integrable. Since, $f$ is given to be continuously differentiable, its derivative is continuous on the domain, and hence integrable.

If you only want to assume that $f'$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ then it is not so simple. Consider the function $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x=0;\\
x^2 \sin (1/x^2), & x \neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
It is differentiable everywhere, and its derivative is continuous on $(0,1)$, but the derivative is unbounded as $x \to 0^+$. You can take a look at the answers to this question for more examples of bounded functions with unbounded derivatives: [Can the graph of a bounded function ever have an unbounded derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257584/279515)

Comment: So, if a function that is defined on [a,b] is continuously differentiable, then its derivative is continuous on [a,b] and not on (a,b)?

Comment: @Kim it depends on your definition. The definition I have seen is that $f : [a.b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be differentiable if there is an open set $U \subset [a,b]$ such that $f$ can be extended to a continuously differentiable function on $U$.

Comment: This isn't correct. The derivative can become unbounded near $a,b$ and we need care to conclude the integral makes sense.

Comment: We need OP's definition of continuously differentiable to know if this is correct.

Comment: @Wojowu quite right, this is really sloppy of me. I am reverting my answer to its previous form.

Comment: @ZachBoyd quite right, this is really sloppy of me. I am reverting my answer to its previous form.

Comment: @Kim Correction to my first comment: I meant to say "$f : [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *continuously* differentiable if $\dots$"

Answer (score 5):

If, according to your question, $f'$ is continuous on a bounded interval (i.e. a compact set), it makes no doubt it is Riemann-integrable (and hence also Lebesgue integrable):

> A bounded function on a compact interval $[a, b]$ is Riemann integrable
>   if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere (the set of its
>   points of discontinuity has measure zero, in the sense of Lebesgue
>   measure).

See: [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)

Comment: @Brahadeesh I did not realize I had so much typos in my answer, thanks for the corrections.

Comment: As in the other answer, we need to be careful about whether f' is continuous on (a,b) or [a,b] since there are different ways of handling the endpoints, and it can change the answer.

Comment: @ZachBoyd Yes sure, here I assumed that $f'$ was continuous on $[a,b]$ as it was not explicitly stated otherwise in the question

Comment: @PicaudVincent Interesting. So if I am supposed to prove some result using a certain set of assumptions, I can make additional assumptions as long as it is not explicitly stated otherwise? Solving my exercise sheets will become much easier now :)