# How can prove or disprove that bounded smooth functions have a bounded derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, smooth-functions

How can prove or disprove that bounded smooth functions have a bounded derivative ? 
For example cosinx is bounded and smooth and has bounded derivative . I can’t think of a proof to show that the claim is true ,nor can I think of a counterexample. Even a hint would be very useful .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257584/can-the-graph-of-a-bounded-function-ever-have-an-unbounded-derivative

Comment: Since you're requiring your function to be smooth and bounded, consider a function that has bounded oscillations. Can you make it so that these oscillations grow more and more (are unbounded)?